# Query can't find substring in comma separated as fields of the table

Tags: mysql, sql

The `LOCATE` and `FIND_IN_SET` Functions don't work as expected. The result of each function should be 1 if it is 0-value.

VALUES

`concat(',',t_insercion.fkCno2011,',')` *value is* `,305,`

`v_curso_cnos.cnos` *value is* `,,305,606,`

FUNCTIONS

```
locate(v_curso_cnos.cnos, concat(',',t_insercion.fkCno2011,','))

find_in_set(concat(',',t_insercion.fkCno2011,','), v_curso_cnos.cnos)
```

And the query is:

```
SELECT r_cursoalumno.fkCurso AS idCurso,
       r_cursoalumno.fkPersona AS persona,
       v_curso_cnos.cnos,
       concat(',',t_insercion.fkCno2011,',') as idCno,
       locate(v_curso_cnos.cnos, concat(',',t_insercion.fkCno2011,',')) as cmp1, 
       find_in_set(concat(',',t_insercion.fkCno2011,','), v_curso_cnos.cnos) as cmp2
FROM v_curso_cnos
  INNER JOIN (r_cursoalumno
  LEFT JOIN t_insercion ON r_cursoalumno.fkPersona = t_insercion.fkPersona)
   ON v_curso_cnos.id = r_cursoalumno.fkCurso
WHERE r_cursoalumno.fkPersona = 20386
```

The query result is this but **locate** and **find_in_set** should be returning a non-zero value.  Why are they not?

```
idCurso persona    cnos         idCno   cmp1   cmp2
____________________________________________________
453       20386  ,,305,608,    ,305,      0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to switch the order of your parameters in your call to LOCATE.

Based on your output, `v_curso_cnos.cnos` returns `,,305,608,`, while `concat(',',t_insercion.fkCno2011,',')` returns `,305,`.

The [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function attempts to find an occurrence of the first string within the second one.  In your case, you are trying to find `,,305,608,` within `,305,`.

[`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) searches for an occurrence of the first string within a **comma-separated string list**.  That means it assumes that all ',' are delimiters, and not part of a string.  In your case, you are trying to find `,305,` within `,,305,608,`, but the function interprets your second string as a list of five strings, `''`, `''`, `'305'`, `'608'`, and `''`; none of which contain `,305,`.  In addition, the documentation states the following:

> This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a
>   comma (“,”) character.